# How not to refetch data on revisiting the visited page on react?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-router-dom, router

Suppose I have two routes `/dashboard` and `/profile`. Now I first visit `/dashboard` , data is fetched and shown on the page . Then I goto `/profile` page again data is fetched and displayed . Now when i go back to `/dashboard` page I dont want to fetch data again. How can I implement this in react? Any help will be great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create your own cache mechanism using redux or context api,
2. you can use react-query, it has inbuilt advanced caching option to fetch data

Comment: Can you give insight or share link to do so using using context ?

Comment: you can keep global states using react context, when you first fetch data related to dashboard set it to state in react context, when you come again check whether previous data is available in the state, if available get it from the state otherwise fetch from the api and set those data to state to use in next time